# Can we onebox TVTropes?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Because, you know, that would be fun:

[image]

Perhaps only in Gaming/SciFi/TV&M?

Comment: ... or *everywhere*...

Comment: Dear productivity, It will never work out between us.  I'm sorry.

Comment: @juergend [Read up about it here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TVTropesWillRuinYourLife)

Comment: I've never got the big "thing" with TVTropes. I'll read the linked article and...that's it. It's worse with Wikipedia when I "link surf"  though, that's a time drain (read about something, click on a link within that article, read about that, etc).

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Oh yeah, good thinking. TV Tropes should definitely be oneboxed on [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/).  ;)

Comment: What does "onebox" mean?

Comment: @EmilVikström When you paste certain links in chat, they expand to show a preview of the content, like in my picture above. Currently TVTropes does not do this, my picture is only a mockup.

Comment: @tombull89 the term you're looking for is "[wiki-walk](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WikiWalk)"

Comment: [Yes, please.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatCouldPossiblyGoWrong)

Comment: [I fully support this feature request.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CaptainObvious)

Comment: It's already done. Just link to any answer on SFF that isn't following an identification request

Comment: I don't know why I upvoted this, it will just waste even more of my time once the boxes start popping up >.<