# Can we get oneboxing for Kickstarter in chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

I am seeing more and more links to kickstarter projects in chat, at least on [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), and I saw that Kickstarter videos gets embeded when linked on Facebook.

I was wondering if we could get some oneboxing for kickstater pages in the chat showing some of the information about the kickstarter and embedding the video if possible.

Comment: [There are more important things to onebox first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176586/15021)